# MySql Select From 4 Different Tables

Tags: mysql, select

I have a MySql query problem. The tables I'm using are very large, so I listed a simple example that I can then use in my more complex table structure.

Lets say the tables are the following.

```
House(id, name)
Person(id, name, house_id)
Car(id, name, person_id, type)
CarEngine(id, name, hp)
```

Each Person belongs to a House. Each Car belongs to a Person. Each Car has a CarEngine with the same primary key (id).

How would I select only the name from each table while selection all the information from CarEngine from these tables efficiently where Car type is truck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select p.name as PersonNamee, h.name as HouseName, c.name as CarName, 
    e.id as CarID, e.name as EngineName, e.hp
from Person p
inner join House h on p.house_id = h.id
inner join Car c on p.id = c.person_id
inner join CarEngine e on c.id = e.id
where c.type = 'truck'
```

Comment: Is there any way to use the select * from the CarEngine table? The tables I'm using have over 50 columns, so the select * for only that table would be awesome.

Comment: After some google searches it looks like I could use CarEngine.* for that table to select everything. Thanks again!